# How to encode jsonarray on Swift 4 ios

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

I have a JSON Array like that

```
[
    {
        "value" : "temp",
        "value2" : "temp2",
        "value3" : "temp3",
    },
    {
       "value" : "temp";
       "value2" : "temp2",
       "value3" : "temp3",
    },  {
       "value" : "temp",
       "value2" : "temp2",
       "value3" : "temp3",
    }
]
```

I try to parse that on swift 4 for ios app. 
I dont find any solve about this subject.
I have tried a lot of code like that

```
let jsonpars = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [AnyObject]
```

Comment: The string is not valid JSON.

Comment: Please search: [There are more than 2700 related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+parse+JSON). In Swift 4 you can use [`JSONDecoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder)

Comment: Like Aris said this is wrong JSON format so fix that first than we can talk

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you've provided is invalid. Correct JSON format should look like this:

1. Replace each occurrence of `=` with `:`
2. Replace each `;` with a comma

The result should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "value":"temp",
        "value2":"temp2",
        "value3":"temp3",
    },
    ...
]
```

Then, the parsing code example you provided should work fine.

Your example JSON looks like what gets printed out after parsing. For example:

```
let jsonpars = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [AnyObject]

print(jsonpars)
```

results in a *debug* version of JSON output:

```
[{
    value = temp;
    value2 = temp2;
    value3 = temp3;
 }, {
 ...
]
```

The *real* JSON, the data you want to parse, has to have colons and commas.

Answer (score 0):

Using [quicktype](https://quicktype.io?l=swift), I generated this model and conversion code for your sample (after correcting the syntax issues):

```swift
import Foundation

struct Value: Codable {
    let value, value2, value3: String
}

extension Array where Element == Value {
    static func from(json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) -> [Value]? {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else { return nil }
        return [Value].from(data: data)
    }

    static func from(data: Data) -> [Value]? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try? decoder.decode([Value].self, from: data)
    }

    var jsonData: Data? {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        return try? encoder.encode(self)
    }

    var jsonString: String? {
        guard let data = self.jsonData else { return nil }
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

Then you can deserialize like this:

```swift
let values = [Value].from(json: """
    [
        {
            "value": "temp",
            "value2": "temp2",
            "value3": "temp3"
        },
        {
           "value": "temp",
           "value2": "temp2",
           "value3": "temp3"
        },
        {
           "value": "temp",
           "value2": "temp2",
           "value3": "temp3"
        }
    ]
""")!
```